# Payment gateway failure using checkout.js version 61

Tags: payment-gateway, checkout, payment-processing, mastercard

I have been trying to test online payments using the MasterCard Payment gateway with no success and I am in dire need of some experienced assistance.

Below is my code where I successfully retrieve 'session.id' and insert it into Checkout.configure({}).

Once the payment modal window is open, I am able to insert the test card number and CVV number and then I am directed to the ACS Emulation portal whereby I click submit.

After that it redirects and I am left with an error as in the screenshot below. In my merchant portal I can see that only an Authorization was done but not a Purchase.

The CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION request:
`'{"apiOperation":"CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION","order":{"amount":'.$grand_total.',"currency":"JOD","id":"'.$order_id.'"},"interaction":{"operation":"PURCHASE","returnUrl":"https://www.oursite.com/thankyou","cancelUrl":"https://www.oursite.com/checkout",}}';`

I have also noticed that there are Security errors caught in the console between redirects from the payment portal and ACS Emulation which I am suspecting might have something to do with it but I assume those are beyond my control as they do not originate from my site... or do they?

Can anyone help with this?

```
<script src="https://mepspay.gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/61/checkout.js"
          data-error="errorCallback"
          data-cancel="cancelCallback"
          data-complete="https://www.oursite.com/thankyou">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click', '#checkoutBtn', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#checkoutForm').serialize();

      $(this).prop("disabled", true);
      $(this).html(
        `<span class="text-light spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span> Checking Out...`
      );
        $.ajax({
          data: data,
          url:'/shop/checkout',
          type:'post',
          success:function(resp){
            console.log(resp)
            if(resp.status == true){
            startCheckout(resp);
            } else {
              toastr.error(resp.message);
            }
          },error:function(err){
            toastr.error("Unable to process checkout. Please try again later.");
          }
        });
      return false
    });

    function errorCallback(error) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    function cancelCallback() {
          console.log('Payment cancelled');
    }

    function completeCallback(resultIndicator, sessionVersion) {
      console.log(resultIndicator)
    }

    function startCheckout(data) {
        let amount = parseFloat(data.order.grand_total);
          Checkout.configure({
            merchant: '<merchantID>',
            session: {
                id:  data.payment.session.id
             },
            order: {
                amount: amount,
                currency: 'JOD',
                description: 'Warehouse Items',
                id: data.order_id
            },
            interaction: {
                operation: 'PURCHASE',
                merchant: {
                  name: '<our company name>',
                  address: {
                      line1:  'Amman',
                      line2: 'Jordan'
                  }
                }
            }
          });

          Checkout.showLightbox();
      }

</script>
```

**After Redirect back to payment gateway with error:**

[image: After Redirect back to payment gateway with error]

**After redirect to ACS emulator with console errors:**

[image: After redirect to ACS emulator with console errors]

Answer (score 0):

it is a matter of test card .. you should be strict with the one in documentation

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).